# Ajax woocommerce product grid best practice theory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

First post so please be kind :)

EDIT: Ok, lets try it like this to rephrase as a more focused question:
(I removed the original phrasing as it would just be unnecessary reading)

I am working towards creating a smooth product grid for my wordpress/woocommerce site. I'm aiming for as close to instant filtering/sorting/page changes as possible.

The way I see it there are three options for a grid:

1. Load first 25 products through the normal wordpress loop (for example) and perform an ajax call for each filter, sort or page change
2. Load all products at once into a json object and perform filter, sort and pagenation functions on the fly
3. Load the first 25 products through the loop and in the background make an ajax call for all products and utilise as in option 2

I would think the third option is best for speed as little delay in initial page load and whilst the initial ajax call is a bit bulky (1.2mb for 400 products) it means no further calls are needed. This potentially gets a bigger issue when the store starts listing thousands of products

Can anyone give a few insights into the pros or cons of any of these approaches to help me work out which option is best to pursue? (or suggest any more practical options)

Comment: The muuri grid demo - [link] (https://codepen.io/bcwang/pen/OxRMeb)

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful response with a more focused question. I also suggest adding some tags for the appropriate subjects, like `ajax`.